# Host a web application online

Tags: web-services, web-hosting

I have created a web service with a NoSQL database, I wish to host this using some sort of cloud storage so I can access the web service and database anywhere. I have never done this before so I'm not sure where to start. Any suggestions of where I could host the service and database would be hugely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AWS, a lot of people like Rackspace. However any hosting company can store your DB for you.

**Heres what I use, Check out AWS Free Tier with Amazon RDS, Its free under the teir limit**

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/

750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro Instance usage running MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle BYOL or SQL Server (running SQL Server Express Edition) – enough hours to run a DB Instance continuously each month
20 GB of DB Storage: any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic storage

10 million I/Os

20 GB of backup storage for your automated database backups and any user-initiated DB Snapshots

In addition to these services, the AWS Management Console is available at no additional charge to help you build and manage your DB Instances on Amazon RDS.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try...will this work with my NoSQL database?

Comment: Just created an account, the console is slightly overwhelming...where do I start?

Comment: go to database > rds > launch database, from there you will get your db link and you can connect from any app. There will be security groups attached to the database that wont allow apps to connect from any ip, you need to change this to allow all traffic to connect to your database. Go to the Ec2 dashboard and select security groups from the left hand side to change this.

Comment: Are you able to take me through a few things? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: No, keep the inbound the same at port 3306, I believe you only need to change outbound, dont quote me on this, try a few things yourself you can change it as many times as you wish